# How to extract between 2 strings when file contains multiple symbols

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, grep

I've been trying to extract form data, from a huge file. I need a very specific pattern which so far fails me.
I have this consistent part of the log:

```
Machine info and user info blah blah blah [senderID=60, 
ipaddress=/10.1.1.11:8443, serviceIdinList=[13], serviceBitbox=11111, 
servicesList= | BeatController | BeatMaker | WaveShow, client=apache,
```

all lines appear like this.
From this line I need to make it look like this:

```
senderID=60, ipaddress=/10.1.1.11:8443, serviceIdinList=[13], 
serviceBitbox=11111, servicesList= | BeatController | BeatMaker | WaveShow,
```

*Note, everything after the "WaveShow," is irrelevant, as is everything before "senderID"

I've tried this command from a post here,

`sed -n '/servicesList=/{s/.*servicesList=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}'`

but it only prints out

`servicesList= | BeatController | BeatMaker | WaveShow`

I have tried to modify it in some iterations with regex, played with grep and sed but no progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is output everything between and including `senderID=` and `WaveShow,`, then you need this `sed` command:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(senderID=.*WaveShow,\).*/\1/p'
```

This will capture everything between those two strings using the `\(` and `\)` brackets and output it using `\1` (and `\2` etc. if you have more captures).

Note that the leading `.*` is "greedy", meaning that if you have the string `senderID=` twice in the input, then the first one will be discarded. If this is not what you want, then `sed` is not the correct tool; `perl` can handle this. The command then becomes:

```
perl -ne 'print if s/.*?(senderID=.*WaveShow,).*/$1/'
```

`-n` means "execute a loop for each line of input, and don't print the line at the end of the loop". `-e` specifies the expression to execute inside the loop.

The `?` after the `.*` changes the `*` to match at little as possible (i.e. match non-greedily). The brackets cause perl to group that part and to capture it, which then can be used as `$1` for the first capture, `$2` for the second, etc.

However that is not optimal way of doing it in perl. This is a lot better as it does not involve changing strings needlessly, capturing the text and printing just that:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /(senderID=.*WaveShow,)/'
```

There are probably many more ways of doing this in perl, perhaps even more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Is the trailing comma required?

If not, this should work:

`grep senderID filename | cut -d '[' -f 2- | cut -d ',' -f -5`

Output:

`senderID=60, ipaddress=/10.1.1.11:8443, serviceIdinList=[13], serviceBitbox=11111, servicesList= | BeatController | BeatMaker | WaveShow`